# cubevalue won't resolve, gives n/a

Tags: excel

I'm trying to get cubevalue() to work for the first time, with a simple top level example:

```
=CUBEVALUE("CUBE_SERVER","[Measures].[Budget]","[ADimension].[AFieldName].&[AValue]")
```

But, I just get N/A each time.

Comment: Can you post a link to a redacted workbook ([mcve]) made available on a public file share? `CUBEVALUE` functions require too much information to be handled with what you have provided.

Comment: I suspected that, it's not worth my job to to post even a redacted version.  I'll keep on working on the problem and post if/when I make progress. Thanks for responding.

Comment: That's a shame but perfectly understandable. If nothing else, try using [F5], Special, Errors to see if there are errors in your data.